# innerHTML to execute multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Iam using innerHTML in script part of my HTML file.

```
    document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML="<font size=4 color=blue><b>Process</b></font><br>"
```

If it fites in single line ,it is working great,
but I want to place multiple lines of HTML code in innerHTML , Is it possible ?

```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "

    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    CPU Information
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    No of Cores:
    1
    Speed of each core in Mhz:
    cpu MHz     : 2399.318
    model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5645  @ 2.40GHz
    CPU Load:
    0.1
    Top CPU using process/application
    -------------------------------------
    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
    1 root      15   0 10364  680  576 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.46 init               
    ";
```

Answer (score 21):

Use ` (backtick) instead of ' or ", it will do the job.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
CPU Information
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
No of Cores:
1
Speed of each core in Mhz:
cpu MHz     : 2399.318
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5645  @ 2.40GHz
CPU Load:
0.1
Top CPU using process/application
-------------------------------------
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
1 root      15   0 10364  680  576 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.46 init               
`;
```

Comment: This is the best answer! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The most robust way is to use string concatenation:

```
document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = 
    "<font size=4 color=blue>" +
    "<b>Process</b>" +
    "</font>" +
    "<br>";
```

Although you *can* do it with line continuations:

```
document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = 
    "<font size=4 color=blue>\
<b>Process</b>\
</font>\
<br>";
```

Note that leading whitespace on subsequent lines **is** part of the string.

---

All that said: If you're doing this a lot, you might consider using a templating engine or similar, so you don't have your HTML intermixed with your JavaScript.

Comment: Here the HTML part Iam placing in innerHTML is dynamic in nature, That is being added here by some scripting. So, this way wont suits sir.

Comment: @RaviKishore: What does it being dynamic have to do with anything? You'd still use string concatenation (or a templating engine). If you have a situation **different** from your question, then due respect, why not make your question an accurate reflection of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Could you please do for this case:<br/>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
   "<font color=red>=====================================================================</font><br> 
            <font size=5 color=blue><b>Health Check Report (CPU-Memory-Disk-Processes)</b></font><br> 
  <font color=red>=====================================================================</font><br>";
   <br>
<b>IP Address:</b> 10.2.3.4<br>
<br>
<b>Hostname:</b>
H1
<br>
<b>Kernel Version:</b>
2.6.18-308.4.1.el5
<br>
<b>Uptime:</b>
52 days
<br>

Comment: @RaviKishore: Code in comments is unreadable. If you want to improve the question, use the "edit" link on the question.